# Calling and initializing static member function of class

Tags: c++, class, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class A {
public:
 int f();
 int (A::*x)();
};

int A::f() {
 return 1;
}

int main() {
 A a;
 a.x = &A::f;
 printf("%d\n",(a.*(a.x))());
}
```

Where I can initialize the function pointer correctly. But I want to make the function pointer as static, I want to maintain single copy of this across all objects of this class.
When I declare it as static

```
class A {
public:
 int f();
 static int (A::*x)();
};
```

I am unsure of the way/syntax to initialize it to function f. Any resource would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A static pointer-to-member-function (I guess you already know this is different from a pointer to a static member function) is a kind of static member data, so you have to provide a definition outside the class like you would do with other static member data.

```
class A
{
public:
   int f();
   static int (A::*x)();
};

// readable version
using ptr_to_A_memfn = int (A::*)(void);
ptr_to_A_memfn A::x = &A::f;

// single-line version
int (A::* A::x)(void) = &A::f;

int main()
{
   A a;
   printf("%d\n",(a.*(A::x))());
}
```

Comment: I didnt know about "using", prefer it slightly more than typedef. Thanks a ton for the answer

Comment: when doing the initialization, I am getting an error, "qualified name is not allowed" .. I am wondering if thats due to compiler related ?

Comment: Well, I did move "ptr_to_A_memfn A::x = &A::f;" inside main, so I am guessing I am messing up the namespace

Comment: A definition for a static data member really does have to be at namespace scope, not in any function.  static data members exist from the beginning of the program.  If you like, you can do `=nullptr` in the definition and then assign to `&A::f` in main using an ordinary assignment statement (modifying the existing static data member not defining a new one)